# SVG drag and drop

Tags: svg

Please can someone help?

I need to drag and drop small spot circles representing room sensors onto a floor Layout rendered inline (binary) into the browser.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score -2):

Download the SVG, add points via SVG program (for example [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/)), upload the SVG again.

If the SVG is displayed completely as a file in your browser (i.e. the URL ends with ".svg" or something like that), so the browser handles the drag and drop, which probably isn't implemented to work with SVG in any way, as your browser is probably not layed out to *edit* SVG files.

If the SVG is embedded somehow into an HTML site you might have a chance if you use JavaScript or something alike to edit the SVG in the browser, implying you can change the JavaScript on that site because you can access it or have a plugin for that.

Oh yeah, maybe there is a plugin for your browser to edit SVGs, who knows?

Comment: I would like to know why I got downvoted. My answer isn't false, rude or anything, is it?

Comment: Probably because your answer provides no useful help to the OP at all.

Comment: May be I did not explain myself very well. What I need is after I have rendered an SVG Image from a Binarywrite call to an MVC method, I then need to be able to drag elements from a toolbar and place them on the drawing. a bit similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/cyur7/. the effect that I am trying to achieve is something lije this https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/e5q6vnLt/ with instead of the green background my svg should be loaded. I also need to be able to record the position in a database. Can someone please help ?